# google Try Sign-In for Android idToken:null

Tags: android, sign

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start?hl=zh-tw

I followed this page , step by step.

I can sign, get Id, E-MAIL and use `SignInActivity`.

but when i try to get IdTokenActivity , it always give me  "onActivityResult:GET_TOKEN:success:false"

and "idToken:null";

I try to set .requestIdToken(server_client_id) to "Web application Client ID"  but still can not sign and "idToken:null";

I do not know what I miss?

please help me,Thanks a lot!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVywY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow step 4 correctly?

> The sample's IdTokenActivity and ServerAuthCodeActivity examples require you to specify an OAuth 2.0 web client ID. In a real app, this client ID would represent your app's backend server. To create a client ID:
>
> Open the Credentials page.
>   Click Add credentials > OAuth 2.0 client ID.
>   Select Web application.
>   Click Create.
>   Your new client ID is displayed. Copy and paste the client ID into your project's strings.xml file:
>
> `<string name="server_client_id">YOUR_SERVER_CLIENT_ID</string>`

Did you go to the Credentials page and create an OAuth 2.0 client ID?

Comment: yes !! I create and set like this picture.  (thanks your help ^^)[link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/OVywY.png

Comment: Where did you get the server client id? Did you create it yourself? Show screen of credentials page.

Comment: [link]https://console.developers.google.com from this page → Credentials → New credentials → OAuth client ID →  Web application .  Happy new year !!!

Comment: Strange, what country are you from? On Chinease phones this won't work I think.

Comment: maybe "real app" is right answer;because I just package APK and install in my phone ,maybe I need upload to googleplay?

Comment: You shouldn't need to update to Google Play. Did you get the generate .json file and add it to app folder?

Comment: Yes!! I download "google-services.json" and "client_secret_xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercont‌​ent.com.json" in My app folder;